Keda scaledObject unable to connect to DataDog in Azure Kubernetes Service - 403 Forbidden
Keda is installed in a dedicated namespace.
The Keda scaledObject, Deployment and other dependencies in a dedicated namespace
Using this code - https://github.com/waiyanwh/keda-datadog-demo/tree/master/keda/scalers/datadog.
Getting 403 Forbidden - when I try to use Datadog scaler following this steps https://keda.sh/docs/2.7/scalers/datadog/
There is no problems when I try invoke API from local machine via CURL using same apiKey and appToken.
Is there anything specific required for AKS + DataDog using KEDA scaledObject ?
KEDA Version:2.14.0
Kubernetes Version:1.29.2
Platform:AKS

I see you have asked this question on https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/4441. Check if your cluster has outbound internet access to reach the Datadog API endpoints. Sometimes NSG rules can restrict access. Verify the secrets are correctly base64 encoded. Check the logs of the KEDA operator for more details. Having said that, Stackoverflow is for programming related question.

Thanks @Arko for the responce. Resolved after using the correct url for datadogSite
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
name: datadog-trigger-auth
namespace: dev-keda-test-ns
spec:
secretTargetRef:
# Required: API key for your Datadog account
 # Optional: Datadog site. Default: "datadoghq.com"


parameter: datadogSite
name: datadog-secrets
key: datadogSite
mine was - us3.datadoghq.com


Good to know Ravi, I am putting this as answer for this question for future reference for StackOverflow community if someone faces similar issue. Feel free to add additional points to enhance the answer. Thanks

As mentioned by Ravi, the issue was related to the datadogSite parameter. If using a different Datadog site (e.g us3.datadoghq.com), it needs to be specified in the TriggerAuthentication configuration.
trigger-authentication.yaml
apiVersion: keda.sh/v1alpha1
kind: TriggerAuthentication
metadata:
  name: datadog-trigger-auth
  namespace: default
spec:
  secretTargetRef:
    - parameter: apiKey
      name: datadog-secret
      key: apiKey
    - parameter: appKey
      name: datadog-secret
      key: appKey
    - parameter: datadogSite
      name: datadog-secret
      key: datadogSite

datadog-secret.yaml
apiVersion: v1
kind: Secret
metadata:
  name: datadog-secret
  namespace: default
type: Opaque
data:
  apiKey: <base64-encoded-datadog-api-key>
  appKey: <base64-encoded-datadog-app-key>
  datadogSite: us3.datadoghq.com


By specifying the datadogSite parameter in the TriggerAuthentication configuration and ensuring that the secret contains the correct base64-encoded Datadog site value, the 403 Forbidden error was resolved.
Reference:
https://docs.datadoghq.com/cloudcraft/getting-started/generate-api-key/
https://keda.sh/docs/1.5/concepts/authentication/#:~:text=TriggerAuthentication%20allows%20you%20to%20describe,IT%20to%20configure%20the%20authentication.
